# Can we use Nested Queries to replace for Join since Join is so long (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my problem. I got a table Meaning, Word, Relation. 1 word can has many meanings & 1 meaning can have many words.

```
ID - Meaning
1 - red car is xxx
2 - red car also mean xxx
4 - ontime is sss
5 - cool is yyy
....
```

```
ID - Word
1 - red car
2 - cat man
4 - Red Car
5 - cool
....
```

```
RelationID-wordID- meaningID
1 - 1 - 1
2 - 4 - 1
3 - 1 - 2
....
```

Each table is pretty long about 100K rows.

Here is what i want, let say the user search for `red car`, it will show

```
RelationID-wordID- meaningID - word - meaning
1 - 1 - 1 - red car - red car is xxx
3 - 1 - 2 - red car - red car also mean xxx
2 - 4 - 1 - Red Car - red car is xxx
```

We can do the JOIN but it took so long for my big table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Word w,
      Relation r,
      Meaning m 
WHERE w.ID=r.wordID 
  AND r.meaningID=m.ID
  AND LOWER(w.text)=LOWER('red car')
```

However, if i make 3 separated queries:

```
SELECT id,
       Word 
FROM Word 
WHERE LOWER(w.text)=LOWER('red car')
```

it will return 1 & 4 / 'red car', 'Red Car'

then 
    SELECT meaningID 
    FROM Relation 
    WHERE wordID in (1,4)`

it will return 1 & 2

after that 
    SELECT Meaning 
    FROM Meaning 
    WHERE id in (1,2)`

it will return 'red car is xxx' & 'red car also mean xxx'

finally I use program to combine these data together. The performance is very fast, but the downside is that there are too many steps. So my question is

Can we make just 1 nested query to get all the needed data?

a query similar to this:

```
SELECT m.*,
       r.relationID,
       w.word 
FROM Meaning m
WHERE m.ID IN 
             (SELECT r.meaningID 
              FROM Relation r 
              WHERE r.wordID IN 
                               (SELECT w.id 
                                FROM Word w 
                                WHERE LOWER(w.text)=LOWER('red car'))))
```

But this query got err as it does not know `r & w`

Comment: Try the long-hand join form (`from Word w inner join relation r on ...`) first, to make sure it's applying your join conditions correctly.

Comment: What indices do you have on your tables? Show actual table schemas and indexes (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`). **Don't use `LOWER()`** on the left side of the comparison condition in `WHERE` clause, because by doing this you effectively force a full scan, unless you are using case sensitive collation. Did you run `EXPLAIN <your query>`? If you didn't do it and post results in your question in textual form.

Comment: i use Case Sensitive Collation, maybe that is the problem

Comment: CREATE TABLE `word` (
  `wordID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
  `text` varchar(255) character set latin1 collate latin1_bin default NULL
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned default '0'
  `createdByMeaningID` int(10) unsigned default '1'
  `insertOrUpdateDateTime` varchar(19) default '2006-01-01 01:01:01'
  PRIMARY KEY  (`wordID`)
  UNIQUE KEY `text` (`text`)
  KEY `createdByMeaningID` (`createdByMeaningID`)
  CONSTRAINT `wordorsentence_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`createdByMeaningID`) REFERENCES `meaning` (`meaningID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I did used Long Hand Join, it 's the same very slow

Comment: You can't forward reference the alias in the SELECT

Comment: even i don't use Collation, it still very slow

Comment: we could use session variable in mysql to store the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a very good solution. That is we have to select the Word table first before doing the Join.

```
select * from (select ID, word from Word where LOWER(word)=LOWER('ddc')) w
join
Relation r on r.wordID=w.ID
join
Meaning m on r.meaningID=m.ID
```

Now it runs very fast!

Comment: As long as you're happy knowing that the query execution includes a table scan for the `Word` table, because the LOWER() function will prevent the index being used.